# Using Power query and or power pivot

Tags: powerquery, powerpivot

I have 10 different excel files with 1000's of rows and each file has different columns apart from 1 common column across all 10. Is there a way to use power query and or power pivot to extract data from these files using the common column?

I have tried Power query but I am unsure how to include all of these columns

Comment: What do you want to do with the 10 tables? Merge (join), append (union), or keep them separate?

Comment: I want to use all the columns so when I search for the common column i can produce tables with relevant data.

Comment: Have you tried @horseyride answer below? It will result in one super table with all rows and columns.

Comment: Did this answer work for you? If so please toggle checkmark next to that answer to mark issue solved

Answer (score 0):

Put the files in their own directory and combine them using this code.  It preserves the file name and tab name for later use

In powerquery, paste into home..advanced editor...

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\mydirectory\mysubdirectory"), 
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".xlsx")),  
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name", "Content"}),   
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "GetFileData", each Excel.Workbook([Content],true)),    
#"Expanded GetFileData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "GetFileData", {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Name"}, {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Sheet"}), 
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded GetFileData",{"Content", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind"}),    
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Removed Columns"[Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))), 
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Data", List,List)   
in  #"Expanded Data"
```

file .. close and load.. back into excel